# Devexpress Gridcontrol Sum of row cell values in specific Column cell

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i am using devexpress gridcontrol and i have table from database and i added 1 column manualy from codebehind :

gridView1.Columns.AddVisible("Total");

i have question how i can give this column valus from summery of rows values like this for example:

```
Name Value value2 value3 Total
g    13     1       6     20
h     2     2       2      6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making an [unbound column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) and setting its [UnboundExpression property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_UnboundExpressiontopic) to a formula that sums your other columns.

See also: [Expressions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument6211)